# CSS - overflow-y: scroll; not turn scrollable and getting >100% of the block height

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to make y-axis scrollable block inside `left-navbar`. And height of this block must fill all free space of the `left-navbar`. This way, that `left-navbar` height is 100% of the page and no more.

But history-overflow is not scrollable, and all `history-item` elements are shown, so they made all `left-navbar` height bigger than the page height.

Also, when page height shrinks, `history-overflow` should fill only free space to make `left-navbar` height not more than 100%. How to make this?

Codepen sandbox example:
https://codepen.io/car1ot/pen/zYqLqKB

*HTML code:*

```
<div className="left-navbar">
    <div className="history">
        <label>History</label>
        <div className="history-overflow">
            <div className="history-item">*...some content here...*</div>
            *...more history-item(s) here...*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS (scss) code:*

```
div.left-navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    div.history {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        div.history-overflow {
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-right: -20px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            overflow-y: scroll;

            div.history-item {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                flex-shrink: 0;
                padding: 0 16px 0 6px;
                height: 40px;
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: 7px;
                margin-bottom: 8px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just kinda guessing, but try adding `overflow: hidden` to `.history` and `.left-navbar`. Hard to tell, if you can provide a jsfiddle/codepen to reproduce the issue it would be easier.

Comment: It would not help...

Comment: https://codepen.io/car1ot/pen/zYqLqKB

Answer (score 0):

If you set `overflow: hidden` to `.history` and `max-height: 100vh` to `.left-navbar`, I think it does what you want. Not sure in the context of your complete layout though (maybe you don't want to use 100vh but a different value there). The important part is that you have to limit the height somewhere.

Comment: It dont work. Please, check out codepen, I've added: https://codepen.io/car1ot/pen/zYqLqKB

Comment: I tried adding those 2 properties to the codepen you shared and it makes the .left-navbar not grow more than 100vh and the content can be scrolled, I'm not sure what issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understan you, this is your solution:

```
body { padding:0; margin:0; }

div.left-navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 290px;
    height: 100vh;  /* This */
    padding: 25px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(#000, 0.1);

    div.history {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height:100%;  /* This */
        div.history-overflow {
            margin-top: 8px;
            margin-right: -20px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            background: rgba(blue, 0.1);
            overflow-y:scroll;
            div.history-item {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                padding: 0 16px 0 6px;
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: 7px;
                margin-bottom: 8px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: rgba(#000, 0.075);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```